# Reading CMS signed enveloped data structure from Base64 encoded envelope

Tags: openssl, cms

Is there a way to read the CMS enveloped data structure from a Base64 encoded signed enveloped message?

What I am particularly interested is to read is which kind of algorithm is used for ephemeral key encryption. 
I have received this message from another party and am supposed to extract the data, but when I read the key encryption algorithm, using BouncyCastle implementation, I get a different value from what is expected (and claimed to be).

It would be of great help if I could use a third party tool to verify that the key encryption is not as what is supposed to be (or to prove myself wrong).

I tried using the `openssl`, with command such as `openssl cms -cmsout -print  -in ~/Downloads/encryptedSignedData.txt`, but it reports an error, no matter which `-inform` argument I use.

Any hint is highly appreciated!

Comment: Commandline `openssl cms` supports only SMIME (which is base64 with linebreaks plus S/MIME headers) PEM (which is base64 with linebreaks plus `----BEGIN/END whatever-----` lines) or DER (binary). If your data is base64 with linebreaks but NO header/trailer (not SMIME _or_ PEM) try converting it to binary: `openssl base64 -d <infile | openssl cms -cmsout -print`. Otherwise show (in your Q) _exactly_ whatever headers/trailers you do have.